# How to commit changed data in a mysql container to a new image

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to create a custom docker image with mysql database in it. I don't need to mount volumes or persist any data between container runs and removals. The goal is to always start containers in the same state. Use them for tests and remove them.

Steps taken:

Start a mariadb container from a generic mariadb image.

```
docker run --name some-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mariadb:10.1.24
1a657ebec5ba
```

Connect to db with mysql client to create a db, user and grant permissions.

```
mysql -uroot -proot -h 0.0.0.0

mysql> CREATE DATABASE store

mysql> CREATE USER 'store'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'store';

mysql> GRANT ALL ON store.* TO 'store'@'%';

mysql> exit
```

Import data.

`mysql -ustore -pstore -h 0.0.0.0 store < ~/mysqldumps/store-2017-06-22-13-55.sql`

At this point the container has the needed user, permissions, data and database.

Commit to the new image.

`docker commit 1a657ebec5ba my-registry/store-test-db:2017-06-30-15-26`

Now, when I start a container from this image on another host. Its just a plain mysql container without my user or database.

What is the correct way to create such image?

Answer (score 0):

Your commands looks ok. How are you connecting to mysql container? It seems that you are working in your host mysql instead of the mysql that is running in the container. Add the port mapping configuration:

So, run as this:

```
docker run -p 3307:3306 --name some-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mariadb:10.1.24
```

Then connect as this to the container mysql:

```
mysql -P 3307 -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -proot
```

Alternatively, you can access to the mysql terminal using `docker exec`:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> mysql -uroot -proot
mysql>
```

---

## Edit

As @raitisd investigated, this is due to the VOLUME that is already defined in the mysql/mariadb base image.

You can use this to solve the issue:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mariadb:10.1.24

RUN cp -r /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-no-volume

CMD ["--datadir", "/var/lib/mysql-no-volume"]
```

Build & run:

```
docker build . -t my-mariadb
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -it my-mariadb
```

Comment: I connect to the container with `mysql -uroot -proot -h 0.0.0.0`. Container is exposing 3306. I dont have mysql-server running on my host. If I stop the container and try again it will just give an error that it cannot connect.

Comment: Are you sure? Your `docker run` command does not show the 3306 port binding.

Comment: The problem is not with connecting to the container. That part works just fine. Its with committing the container to an image.

Comment: check this `docker diff <container-id>` after the modifications. Also, after commit run the image again: `docker exec -it $(docker run -d my-registry/store-test-db:2017-06-30-15-26) mysql -uroot -proot`, then `show databases;`

Comment: But you do have a good point that I don't define what port to expose when i run the container. I guess its because the Dockerfile of mariadb has `EXPOSE 3306`. But when i stop the container then i cannot connect with the same params. So I am pretty sure that I am connecting to the correct mysql. Also if i do `docker ps` I see `0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp`. So somehow it works :D

Comment: Yep I see the database and tables crated after I run the import.

Comment: I am assuming that somehow all the data is mounted because of the original image I use. So when Im committing to a new image it just doesnt commit mounted data. Which makes sense. Maybe I should start with a plain ubuntu container and install mysql and then import my data. That way there are no volumes involved.

Comment: `docker diff` returns `C /run`, `C /run/mysqld`, `C /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`, `C /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, `C /tmp`